# R: Calling apply on a 0 x 0 matrix results in calling FUN(numeric(0)). Why? And can this be prevented?

Tags: r, apply

When running the code

```
f = function(x) print(x)
apply(matrix(numeric(0),0,0), 1, f)
```

my expectation is that nothing should be printed; there are zero rows to apply `f` to, and so `f` should never be called. Instead, `f` is called, once, and prints `numeric(0)`, suggesting that `apply` is calling `f(numeric(0))` (or the equivalent) at some point.

This is a problem in the (non-MWE) code that inspired this question because my actual `FUN` will crash if given numeric(0) as a parameter.

Why is this happening? And is there a parameter that can be fed to `apply` to make it not? I can work around it in this particular case (specifically, by throwing the relevant code inside an `if` block), but it seems like there ought to be a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to prevent the functions from being called, you'll need some sort of `if` statements to check the value before passing it to `apply`.

if you step though the `apply` function by running `debugonce(apply)` before calling the function, you can see `apply` was specially written to always call `FUN` even in the case of an empty margin. For some functions a zero length vector may be a perfectly valid input. That's not `apply`'s decision to make nor an option is has. This is to be constent with the description of value returned from `apply` as described in the "Value" section of the `?apply` help page.

An alternative would be to change your function do it doesn't return an error if passed a zero length vector.

Comment: A zero-length vector may be a valid input, sure. So if I called `apply(matrix(numeric(0), N, 0), 1, f)`, I would expect `f` to be called `N` times, always with parameter `numeric(0)`, because there are `N` rows, even though those rows are empty. And this is true for `N > 0`. So why is it not also true for `N == 0`? Why does that code snippet call `f` twice if `N == 2`, and once if `N == 1`, but _once_ (i.e., **not** the expected zero times) if `N == 0`?

Comment: I don't know what to tell you other than that's just the way the code was written. I'm sure there's some functions out there that depends on that behavior. `apply` has to return something and it's unclear what that would be if you never called the function at all. You can't change the behavior of `apply` so to get the behavior you want, you need to validate your input before passing it to the function. If you don't like that answer, you can email the R developers at the r-devel mailing list.